# C programming exercise: Function Prototype

Tags: c, function, prototype

I am in the midst of reading "C Primer Plus" by Stephen Prata. The 7th programming exercise
of the 5th chapter wants you to "Write a program that requests a type double number and print the value of the number cubed. Use a function of your own design to cube the value and print it. The main() program should pass the entered value to this function."

What am I doing wrong? When I run this, I only get the same number I entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void cube(double n);
int main(void)
{
    double a;
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    cube(a);
    printf("%lf", a);

    return 0;
}

void cube(double n)
{
    n = n * n * n;
}
```

Comment: You're passing _by value_, so `cube` only modifies its local copy of the value you pass it.

Comment: All these answers are wrong. The exercise is to "use a function of your own design to cube the value *and print it*" (emphasis mine). It wants you to print the value from inside your function, not from `main()`, so all these considerations about returning values or passing a pointer are off-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **return** the value!

```
#include <stdio.h>
double cube(double n);
int main(void)
{
    double a;
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("%lf", cube(a));

    return 0;
}

double cube(double n)
{
    n = n * n * n;
    return n;

}
```

If you don't want to return the values then you can use pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void cube(double *n)
{
  *n = (*n) * (*n) * (*n);
}
int main()
{
  double n = 10;
  cube(&n);
  printf("%lf\n",n);
}
```

Comment: Damn, you had my exact solution but with `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: @aglasser Sorry boss! I have the experience! :p ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your function `cube` needs to *return a result*, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double cube(double n);

int main(void)
{
    double a, b;

    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    b = cube(a);      // call `cube()` to get cube of a and save in b
    printf("%lf", b);

    return 0;
}

double cube(double n)
{
    return n * n * n; // return n cubed as function result
}
```

Comment: do _you_ have to answer such questions?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: sure, why not ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `cube()` does cube the value assigned to `a` but does not return the result `n`.

This means that the variable `a` back in main has not changed.

You will need to alter your function prototype such that your cube function can be used as follows:

```
a = cube(a);
```

This will mean that `a` will be updated with the result returned by the function `cube()`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned, your `cube` function must return a value. You can keep the return type as `void` however, if you pass in a *pointer* to `n`. Parenthesis for readability.

```
void cube(int *n)
{
    // dereference the pointer and cube it
    *n = (*n) * (*n) * (*n);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    cube(&n); // address of n variable
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs 27.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the value of `a`, you could pass the address of `a` in main().

```
#include <stdio.h>
void cube(double n);
int main(void)
{
    double a;
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    cube(&a);  
    printf("%lf", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Then in cube(), modify what is pointed to by the pointer `n`.

```
void cube(double *n)
{
    *n = (*n) * (*n) * (*n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Paul Griffiths for carefully reading the question!

Following your advice the code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void cube(double n);
int main(void)
{
    double a;
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    cube(a);

    return 0;
}

void cube(double n)
{
    n = n * n * n;
    printf("%lf", n);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should've passed the `n` in the function `void cube (double n)` as a reference.

```
void cube (double &n)
```

Read about the `reference variables` in C++ here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm.